# What are the best tools to create epub from latex?

Tags: tex4ebook, epub

I have a math-light memoir book, with tables, figures, etc., and tons of convenience macros, which I would like to convert into a document suitable for kindle redistribution, too --- the key one will be printed and pdf, though.

I am presuming that the epub3 format is my best choice for kindle.

The last messages suggest tex4ebook.  Is this the best practice now?

I looked at tex4ebook, but this seems not to be able to go through the tex engine and use my style files and therefore chokes on all sorts of issues.  Is it more like its own high-level interpreter?

Is there a list of what it can deal with well and not so well?  Any macros?  Some macros?  Is there a way to define macros that tex4ebook likes?

experiences appreciated...

regards, /iaw

Comment: Try PanDoc (https://pandoc.org/). I never used that but it could be just what you need.

Comment: Yes, you can configure TeX4ebook for your own styles and macros. If you get errors, it is possible that you redefine some standard commands? Could you make a MWE that shows such issues?

Comment: You can include your own `css`- files via `tex4ebook`, which will add it to the style it creates from `Latex` itself. So, e.g. using `Sigil`, you can delete or rename the `"latex.css"` , which may or may not please you. However, there will be left a lot of extra information in the `html` files ...

Comment: Just let remind ourselves that HTML was intended to display text somehow, not to provide typesetting. Same holds for EPUB, in my view. Though people strive for typesetting via CSS, there was no, is no, and probably will be no guarantee that HTML or EPUB will look identical or at least similar on different webbrowsers or eBook readers ...

Comment: I have found this https://minireference.com/blog/generating-epub-from-latex/ but I cannot tell you if it is a better solution than the others.